Converting API calls into firebase firestore
In my app, all the functionalities were working under API call including Authentication like Login api and Register api calls. But for some reasons, I wish change the flow of authentication through Firebase firestore and i need to store it in firestore database including OTP validation through Mobile Number.
So what are the necessary changes that I have to do in authentication without the help of the any API calls??
I need make authentication process without the help of the api calls and to store all the user data within the firestore itself instead of using to store it in SQL database!!!!

Use this controller


<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    protected $firebase;
    protected $firestore;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->firebase = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(config('services.firebase.credentials'))->createAuth();
        $this->firestore = new FirestoreClient(['projectId' => 'your-project-id']);
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $userProperties = [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ];
        $user = $this->firebase->createUser($userProperties);
        $this->firestore->collection('users')->document($user->uid)->set([
            'email' => $request->email,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
        ]);
        return response()->json(['message' => 'User registered successfully', 'user' => $user]);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $signInResult = $this->firebase->signInWithEmailAndPassword($request->email, $request->password);
        $idToken = $signInResult->idToken();
        return response()->json(['message' => 'User logged in successfully', 'idToken' => $idToken]);
    }

    public function sendOtp(Request $request)
    {
        // Implementation to send OTP using Firebase
    }

    public function verifyOtp(Request $request)
    {
        // Implementation to verify OTP using Firebase
    }
}



Configuration:

Install Firebase and Firestore SDKs:
composer require kreait/firebase-php google/cloud-firestore

Add Firebase Configuration:

Place the serviceAccountKey.json in storage/app.
Add to config/services.php:

'firebase' => [
'credentials' => storage_path('app/serviceAccountKey.json'),
],
Hope this helps


